# How undo the "revoke access" in yammer applications

Tags: development, rest, spfx-webparts, yammer

i cloned a spfx project  from https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-yammer-api and it basicaly search for a name of the user in yammer and return some informations about it. I was able to execute and query yammer rest api just fine, but then i went to my yammer user profile settings and i revoke the access to the application that i registered.

[image]

And now i cannot get the users using the rest api anymore. Always that i make a request its return 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your local storage and cookies and you should get the consent popup again.

Comment: Thanks! It is ok now